# Instruct pm2 to not start multiple instances in json file

Tags: node.js, pm2

The following is the pm2 **process.json** config file. The app is stared using the command

> **pm2 start /root/src/sample_v2/deploy-scripts/processes.json**

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "sample_app_v2",
    "script"      : "bin/www",
    "log_date_format"  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
    "node_args"   : "--harmony",
    "cwd"         : "/root/src/sample_v2",
    "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production",
        "AWESOME_SERVICE_API_TOKEN": "xxx",
        "TZ": "Europe/Amsterdam"
    }
  }]
}
```

> **Output**

```
PM2: 2015-03-31 17:58:58: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:sample id:10
PM2: 2015-03-31 17:58:58: App name:sample id:10 online
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:38 +04:00: Started...[object Object]
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:38 +04:00: mongoclient.connect
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:38 +04:00: Started...[object Object]
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:38 +04:00: mongoclient.connect
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: Started...[object Object]
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: mongoclient.connect
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: Started...[object Object]
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: mongoclient.connect
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: Started...[object Object]
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: mongoclient.connect
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: Started...[object Object]
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: mongoclient.connect
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: Started...[object Object]
sample-10 (out): 2015-02-06 21:39 +04:00: mongoclient.connect
sample-10 (out): 2015-03-31 17:59 +04:00: Started...[object Object]
sample-10 (err):     at Object.274:1 (cluster.js:594:5)
sample-10 (err):     at handleResponse (cluster.js:171:41)
sample-10 (err):     at respond (cluster.js:192:5)
sample-10 (err):     at handleMessage (cluster.js:202:5)
sample-10 (err):     at process.emit (events.js:117:20)
sample-10 (err):     at handleMessage (child_process.js:322:10)
sample-10 (err):     at child_process.js:396:7
sample-10 (err):     at process.handleConversion.net.Native.got (child_process.js:91:7)
sample-10 (err):     at process.<anonymous> (child_process.js:395:13)
sample-10 (err): TypeError: Cannot read property 'getsockname' of undefined
sample-10 (err):     at net.js:1083:27
sample-10 (err):     at Object.274:1 (cluster.js:594:5)
sample-10 (err):     at handleResponse (cluster.js:171:41)
sample-10 (err):     at respond (cluster.js:192:5)
sample-10 (err):     at handleMessage (cluster.js:202:5)
sample-10 (err):     at process.emit (events.js:117:20)
sample-10 (err):     at handleMessage (child_process.js:322:10)
sample-10 (err):     at child_process.js:396:7
sample-10 (err):     at process.handleConversion.net.Native.got (child_process.js:91:7)
sample-10 (err):     at process.<anonymous> (child_process.js:395:13)
```

Looks like the process is tried to start **10** times. How to ask **pm2** to not start multiple instances ?

> **EDIT 2:**

Adding the property

```
"instances"   : 1
```

to the json file works as expected and starts only one process. But it throws the warning

```
[WARN] You should not use the cluster_mode (-i) in production, it's still a beta feature. A front HTTP load balancer or interaction with NGINX will be developped in the future.
```

How to start the process in the **fork-mode** and still have single instance.

Comment: To me it looks like it's only starting once. But there is an error somewhere. Default mode is the `fork_mode` so it'll start only one instance of your process.

Comment: At the start of the app the text **mongoclient.connect** is printed. In this case it is printing 10 times. If only once it is started it would have printed only once.

Comment: @soyuka Also please look at the edit to the question.

Comment: I think that this warning is only showed when using node 0.10. What's your current node version ?

Answer (score 2):

Specify exec_mode and instances keys in json settings:

```
{
  "apps" : [{
  "exec_mode": "fork",
  "instances": 1
  }]
}
```